# linux sockets: Close socket in C

Tags: c, linux, macos

I terminate the server using Ctrl-C which I think will close the socket immediately. However it turns out if I bind the same port it will say binding is failed. I use mac OS X. Any ideas? I even implemented signal handler for ctrl C to close it but still have the same problem.

Comment: linux != osx. they're two completely separate OSes... what do you mean "linux sockets"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get rid of the error with this before you bind it (at least on Linux, I don't know about OSX)

```
 int on = 1;
 setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, on.sizeof); // or sizeof(on) in C
```

When the socket closes, the kernel keeps a handle around in case there's still some pending data on the wire arriving out-of-order or late or something, so it can sanely handle it when it arrives by telling the other side it is closed now instead of delivering those random chunks to the next application. This is called "time_wait" status if you wanna look that up to learn more. It takes a couple minutes before releasing everything to ensure it is clear.

This reuse addr option tells it to not worry about that and just rebind anyway without the wait time.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag when creating your socket. From the man page:

> Indicates that the rules used in validating addresses supplied
>                 in a bind(2) call should allow reuse of local addresses.  For
>                 AF_INET sockets this means that a socket may bind, except when
>                 there is an active listening socket bound to the address.
>                 When the listening socket is bound to INADDR_ANY with a
>                 specific port then it is not possible to bind to this port for
>                 any local address.  Argument is an integer boolean flag.

This way, you can rebind whenever you re-launch your program and there is no active socket bound.

You can also set this flag after the socket creation (but before doing the `bind`) using `setsockopt`. See [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22138619/865281).

Comment: You might want to mention `setsockopt`.